# RaphealJS Resize and mouse shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I have been using RaphealJS to create a vector drawing tool, I have all the drawing completed and working

my issues comes in when I resize the browser window and try to draw the mouse pointer is off from the location that is being drawn.

I use the mouse move event on the browser and draw lines , Like so

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if (IE) {
      var dh = $("#details").height();
      var dw = $("#details").width();
          xx = e.offsetX;
          yy = e.offsetY;
    } else {
       var offset = $("#workcanvas").offset();
       xx = e.pageX - offset.left;
       yy = e.pageY - offset.top;
    }
    if (lineObject != null) {
        lineObject.updateEnd(xx, yy);
    } else {
        lineObject = Line(xx, yy, xx, yy, MasterCanvas);
   }
});
```

I create my canvas and background image

```
var MasterCanvas = Raphael($("#workcanvas").attr("id"));

var MasterBGImage = MasterCanvas.image(imgPath, 0, 0, $("#workcanvas").width(),$("#workcanvas").height());

MasterCanvas.setViewBox(0, 0, $("#workcanvas").width(), $("#workcanvas").height(), true);
```

and in my window resize event  I tried this

```
MasterCanvas.setSize($("#workcanvas").width(), $("#workcanvas").height());
```

Now I have beat my head against this for a few days to no avail. Please note: I can the drawing function work, and as long as the window does not resize every thing is great but when the page resizes the drawing point is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem, it turns out to be a viewBox problem, I had to calculate the mouse position based on the viewBox coordinates not the screen so my original code becomes:

```
 $(document).mousemove(function(e){

    var uupos = MasterCanvas.canvas.createSVGPoint();
    uupos.x = e.clientX;
    uupos.y = e.clientY;
    var ctm = MasterCanvas.canvas.getScreenCTM();
    if (ctm = ctm.inverse())
    uupos = uupos.matrixTransform(ctm);
    x = uupos.x;
    y = uupos.y;

    if (lineObject != null) {
        lineObject.updateEnd(x, y);
    } else {
        lineObject = Line(x, y, x, y, MasterCanvas);
   }
});
```

**Edit:**
Looks like this solution is SVG only though and it does not work in IE8 which is a requirement for me - any ideas.

Is there something like viewBox coordinates in VML